# Drawables on ImageView: how to layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-drawable

Because I'm quite new to Android, I don't know what's the best practice to achieve the following scenario.

Within my main activity I want to display an image (might be ImageView showing a static image or SurfaceView showing a camera preview). That image should support pinch-zoom (pan/zoom). When the user tabs onto the image, I want to add a new child view (Drawable defined in XML). Those drawables should be moved with the finger. The drawables should, of course, stick to their position relative to the ImageView and must move/zoom accordingly.

My questions are:

1. Is my basic idea correct?
2. What layout to use? RelativeLayout, FrameLayout or ViewOverlay (API 18+)
3. Pan/Zoom must be implemented in MainActivity, right?
4. the red Drawables will be children of the ImageView or of the main view?

I'm open for hints or changes or any other best practice.

[image: View structure]

Comment: I like ques's 1st line.

Comment: @Matthias what children the main view is supposed to have? are they complex things like spinners, list views etc or just images buttons etc?

Comment: More or less simple things like decorated circles and rectangles. But the user should be able to tap on them to move them around and each shape should react to a single tap. Currently I implemented my own shape logic and I draw everything on my own in View.onDraw. But I split the visual content of the Drawables into XML files that I simply load from resource and then call drawable.draw(Canvas)

Comment: @Matthias so you really dont want any ViewGroup, but rather just a smart Drawable that can draw several layers e.g. LayerDrawable or my https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable

Comment: Yes, I guess that is suitable for my situation. But I really wonder that there is no built-in solution in Android that any kind of view can be scrolled/zoomed while affected all child layout/views automatically. Really dispointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have two things: a pan/zoom conponent and a Drawable to draw

for the first item you can find several such componenrs on the web (e.g. my https://github.com/pskink/ZoomView) and for the second you can use combined LayerDrawable + BitmapDrawable + InsetDrawable or use my https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on the Drawable part? Because the ImageView is larger than the circles and I got only one image but multiple circles. The question is how to combine them.

Comment: see layerDrawable docs it can combine several Drawables as the layees - in your case you will use BirmapDrawable with an optional padding for the circles ro place them in particulae dpots within the large image

Comment: All examples I can find will pan/zoom just a single ImageView or a View with overridden onDraw method. But I'm looking for a ViewGroup or similar that has to pan/zoom logic that then affects all child views/layouts accordingly.

Comment: I ended up implementing my own custom view overriding onDraw method. But while drawing on the canvas (argument of onDraw) I inflate Drawables that are defined in XML. So this combination suits me.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest implementing a custom view, which will contain all the logic. Solving this problem using multiple views (a separate view for each movable image) would be very hard. I have solved a lot of problems like this by creating a custom view.

Answer (score 1):

Call the above method when the parent's bounds have changed and pass the parent into it. All children that are `ViewGroup` types will be resized. You could potentially call this recursively on each child as well if needed. You may have to call `requestLayout`() on the parent after resizing the children.

```
private void resizeChildren(ViewGroup parent, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    // size is in pixels so make sure you have taken device display density into account
    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View v = parent.getChildAtIndex(i);
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ((ViewGroup)v).LayoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(newWidth, newHeight);
        }
    }
}
```